# Python: understanding method/descriptor binding

Tags: python

I've considered the following example of a decorator:

```py
import functools

class deco:
    def __init__(self, main_func):
        self.main = main_func
        functools.update_wrapper(self, self.main)

    def __call__(self, obj, *args, **kwargs):
        print("decorated call")
        self.main(obj, *args, **kwargs)


class foo:
    @deco
    def bar(self):
        print("called bar")
```

Then, the following code:

```
>> foo.bar
>> foo().bar
```

Produces:

```
<__main__.deco object at 0x0000026BDE10F490>
<__main__.deco object at 0x0000026BDE10F490>
```

So it seems like even through an instance, this is not bound to it.

Using the python docs on methods, I've added a `__get__` method:

```py
class deco:
    def __init__(self, main_func):
        self.main = main_func
        functools.update_wrapper(self, self.main)

    def __get__(self, obj, objtype=None):
        if obj is None:
            return self
        return MethodType(self, obj)

    def __call__(self, obj, *args, **kwargs):
        print("decorated call")
        self.main(obj, *args, **kwargs)
```

Now I get:

```
<__main__.deco object at 0x000001E9C721F790>
<bound method foo.bar of <__main__.foo object at 0x000001E9C7297DD0>>
```

So, I get what `__get__` does, but what is the default behavior without it? What actually happens when doing `foo().bar` without a `__get__`?

Comment: "What actually happens when doing foo().bar without a __get__?" then it simply returns the class variable, since attribute access is not intercepted since the object is not a descriptor, so the`deco` object. Just like if you did `bar = 1` in your `foo` class definition, then did `foo.bar` and `foo().bar`, it would just return `1`.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga So basically, without a `__get__` it treats it like a deco instance attribute in `foo`, but with it it's a method of it, right?

Comment: no, it gets treated like a normal *class* attribute. Not an instance attribute. Again, it's as if you did `bar = 1` in your class definition, defining a class variable `bar` with a vlaue of `1`